# How do I manually remove a column from PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

So I wanna remove a column that is useless in my phpMyAdmin table manually, how do I do that?

Comment: Via Query: `alter table table_name drop column column_name`.. Please start learning SQL queries of DDL, DML etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are on your table you can see the tabs on top of your phpmyadmin view, the second tab should be structure, there you can delete/edit or insert new or old columns.[image]